# Why outputs are different when same query used in SQL server and AWS Aurora bablefish DB instances

Tags: sql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Same Query runs in SQL server instance and AWS Aurora DB (bablefish) instance but gives different output value.
I need to use bablefish supported functions by referring ExistingSQLFuncResult during Migration.

*Any help is much appreciated!!*

Query - Calculating Remaining days left in the current Year:

**sqlsever000instance** -

```
select
    getdate() [Today],
    (datediff(day, getdate(), dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0)) - 1) [ExistingSQLFuncResult],
    (datediff(day, getdate(),cast(convert(char(4), year(getdate())+1, 112) + '0101' as datetime))-1) [AuroraBablefishResult]
```

| Today | ExistingSQLFuncResult | AuroraBablefishResult |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-21 02:00:33.783 | 285 | **285** |

**Bablefish000instance** -

```
select
    getdate() [Today],
    (datediff(day, getdate(),cast(convert(char(4), year(getdate())+1, 112) + '0101' as datetime))-1) [AuroraBablefishResult]
```

| Today | AuroraBablefishResult |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-21 02:00:33.783 | **284** |

Comment: You're abusing `convert(char(4)...`  - why are you doing this?

Comment: Also, `getdate` returns the **server local** datetime, which varies between servers based on how they're configured - presumably your SQL Server instance has a different timezone (and/or daylight savings) setting compared to the Postgres+Babelfish server - so... why aren't you using UTC?

Comment: @Dai, Thank you for the response.
I have to refer the existing SQL functionality and build the same logic.. I tried one of the way that supports in Bablefish . But i would like to know if any better way to implement the remaining days of the current year functionality..

Comment: You can't use the same logic as before because the old logic/code was incorrect, and apparently only worked by _sheer luck_ that the server's timezone was configured as-expected. You need to fix the application code.